# How to create immutable object from mutable in java?

Tags: java, oop, immutability, access-modifiers

How to create immutable Planet so the name doesn't change?  I am struggling as I think it is immutable project with mutable object. Correct me if I am wrong.

Every time I change name in the output also changes. Am I missing something?

I tried to do all fields private and final (not in this example) but I think I am missing some code to work.

I know java.util.Date is deprecated but this is just for example.

```
import java.util.Date;   

public final class Planet {  
    String name;                                                      
    private final Date discoveryDate;  

    public Planet (String name, Date discoveryDate) {               
        this.name = name;
        this.discoveryDate = new Date(discoveryDate.getTime());    
    }

    public String getName() 
        return name;
    }

    public Date getDiscoveryDate() {               
        return new Date(discoveryDate.getTime());     
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Planet Earth = new Planet("Earth Planet", new Date(2020,01,16,17,28));

        System.out.println("Earth");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Earth.getName: " + Earth.getName());
        System.out.println("Earth.getDiscoveryDate: " + Earth.getDiscoveryDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Moreover, [Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-int-int-) has been deprecated since JDK 1.1 (which was released 24 years ago).

Comment: You have not marked `name` as `final`, why that? `Planet` is supposed to be immutable.

Comment: The `Date` class is not only poorly designed and long outdated, as you say, it is also mutable! So a problematic choice for a field in an immutable class (there would be ways around it, but since the date-time classes of java.time are already immutable, the easy solution is to switch to one of those).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

Either:

- Make a `record` like this, in Java 16 and later:
  `public record Planet( String name , LocalDate discovered ) {}`
- Or, before Java 16, make a class where you:

  - Mark all member fields `final` and `private`.
  - Make getter methods as needed, but no setter methods.

## Record

Just use the new [*records* feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16 ([previewed in Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384)).

Define your class as a `record` when its main job is to transparently and immutably carry data. The compiler implicitly creates a constructor, the getters, `hashCode` & `equals`, and `toString`.

Notice that the getter methods implicitly defined in a record do *not* begin with the [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)-style `get…` wording. The getter method is simply the name of member field as defined in the parentheses following the class name.

Of course, if your getter methods provide access to an object that is itself mutable, being contained in a record does nothing to stop the calling programmer from mutating the contained object. Notice in the example class next that both `String` and `LocalDate` classes are themselves immutable by design. So the mutability of a contained object is a non-issue here.

```java
package org.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public record Planet( String name , LocalDate discovered )
{
}
```

Using that record.

```java
Planet Earth = new Planet( "Earth" , LocalDate.of( 2020 , 1 , 16 ) );

System.out.println( "Earth" );
System.out.println( "------------------------------------" );
System.out.println( "Earth.name: " + Earth.name() );
System.out.println( "Earth.discovered: " + Earth.discovered() );
```

When run.

```
Earth
------------------------------------
Earth.name: Earth
Earth.discovered: 2020-01-16
```

## Class

Without the records feature, to make sure a class is immutable you should:

- Mark the member fields `final`. This means the field cannot be assigned a different object after the constructor has finished.
- Mark the member fields `private`. This means objects of other classes will not have direct access to read or change those fields.
- Provide getter methods, if needed, but no setter methods. By convention, the JavaBeans-style `get…` or `is…` naming is used.

You should also provide appropriate override implementations of `hashCode`, `equals`, and `toString`. Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) will help generate the source code for those.

```java
package org.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Planète
{
    // Member fields
    final String name;
    final LocalDate discovered;

    // Constructors
    public Planète ( String name , LocalDate discovered )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        Objects.requireNonNull( discovered );
        this.name = name;
        this.discovered = discovered;
    }

    // Getters (read-only immutable class, no setters)
    public String getName ( ) { return this.name; }

    public LocalDate getDiscovered ( ) { return this.discovered; }

    // Object class overrides
    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Planète planète = ( Planète ) o;
        return getName().equals( planète.getName() ) && getDiscovered().equals( planète.getDiscovered() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getName() , getDiscovered() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Planète{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | discovered=" + discovered +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Using that class.

```java
Planète Earth = new Planète( "Earth" , LocalDate.of( 2020 , 1 , 16 ) );

System.out.println( "Earth" );
System.out.println( "------------------------------------" );
System.out.println( "Earth.getName: " + Earth.getName() );
System.out.println( "Earth.getDiscoveryDate: " + Earth.getDiscovered() );
```

## Side issues

Do not start a decimal integer literal with `0`. The leading zero makes the number [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) rather [decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal). So your code passing `2020,01,16` should be `2020,1,16`.

Never use the `Date` class, nor `Calendar` or `SimpleDateFormat`. These terrible classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. In code above, we used [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

Answer (score -1):

Planet is immutable but field `name` should be private.

Comment: How is a `Planet` object immutable if `name` is not `private`?

Comment: With `private name` it is, that's what I meant.